# Video editing software like iMovie, for Windows?

Tags: video-editor, windows, imovie

Although skeptical at first, I took a liking to iMovie and began to rely on it heavily to edit many music videos. What I liked about iMovie was it's easy to use feel when it came to placing a clip exactly where you need it to be within the audio of a song. I have a Windows computer now, and cannot use the new iMovie anymore. Looking for something as similar as possible.

I'm looking for software that could work similarly on Windows, and the key main I really only need are:

- Image stabilization
- Color Correction
- Speed/Duration settings
- Easy to use adjustment of placement of a clip

Any suggestions? Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd recommended the the Sony Vegas Suite. It's paid but offers what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I've not used it, but Microsoft makes [Microsoft Movie Maker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/movie-maker). It might meet your needs.

There are also some open source video editors you might have luck with:

ShotCut - http://www.shotcut.org - kind of new, might be buggy

Blender - http://www.blender.org - it's a 3D modelling app with video editing capabilities

Lightworks - http://www.lwks.com - there's a "buy" button, but there's also a free version, as I understand it.

If you don't mind using Linux, you can also try out [OpenShot](http://openshot.org) and [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org).

Comment: Also: Wax http://www.debugmode.com/wax/ and Lightworks - a professional app with a free version http://www.lwks.com/

Comment: Lightworks and shortcut are your best bet.

Comment: For future readers: Movie Maker is discontinued and its replacement is exclusively available on Windows 10. Blender worked well for me, though the user interface has a steep learning curve. I have not tried the other options and have a bias toward open source software. A good 30 minute tutorial for combining, cutting and fading clips is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42AQ_EtRVq4).

Answer (score 1):

As someone else mentioned, [Windows Movie Maker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/movie-maker) is a free option that would fit most of your needs. However, if you don't mind paying a little bit for your software, I'd recommend [Adobe Premiere Elements](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere-elements.html). It's a super-simplified version of [Adobe Premiere Pro](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere.html) that should be able to do everything you're asking for.

Comment: Movie maker does not have stabilization or colour grading. So it isn't really an option.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, I use Hitfilm 3 Express, which is free [here](https://hitfilm.com/express).

It's actually very easy to use and isn't export limited like the free version of Lightworks.  Plus if you decide at some point you want the more advanced features of the Pro version you can buy them piecemeal in packs for like $10-$25 rather than shelling out $300 for the full upgrade.

I'd been holding out for the windows version of openshot for a few years but managed to get Hitfilm 3 Express for free during a promo and it was decent.  3 is pretty great software though, I might not even switch to openshot when it comes out...and I put money into their kickstarter so I could get it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are only two version of iMovie: one for Mac OS X (iMac/Macbook) and one for iOS (iPhone/iPad). If you are a Windows user, you'd better to download an alternative to iMovie for Windows to replace iMovie.

There are numerous of tools that claim to completely do what iMovie does. For more information, visit here: [**iMovie for Windows**](http://www.faasoft.com/video-editing/imovie-for-windows.html).

Or

Windows Movie Maker is another tool to edit video in Windows. visit [**here**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18614/windows-essentials#t1=overview) .

If you are not satisfied with the both above, you can also try **VirtualDub, Pinnacle Studio, Shotcut**, etc.

Hope it will help you more or less.